# Ruby Iterating through 2D arrays and Populating with random data

Tags: ruby, multidimensional-array, random

I have to generate a dynamically sized 2D array with a predetermined value in the first index of each sub array, three random values in each of the three following indices (each falling in a different range), and finally, a calculated total of the three random indices. Here is what I have so far.

## Sample code

```
print("Please enter the number of athletes competing in the triathalon: ")
field=gets.to_i

    count=1
    athlete = Array.new(5)
    triathalon = Array.new(field){athlete}
    triathalon.each do
            athlete.each do
                    athlete.insert(0,count)
                    athlete.insert(1,rand(30..89))
                    athlete.insert(2,rand(90..119))
                    athlete.insert(3,rand(120..360))
            #calculate total time per athlete
                    athlete.insert(4,athlete[1]+athlete[2]+athlete[3])
                    count+=1
            end
    end
```

Comment: The code seems to hang during the generation process. Running it without the nested athlete.each loop results in a clean run, but only generating one repeated set of athlete data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible option is using [Range](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Range.html) and mapping the range using [Enumerable#map](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-map).

For example given `n = 3` athletes, basic example:

```
(1..n).map { |n| [n] } #=> [[1], [2], [3]]
```

So, adding some of your specifications to the basic example:

```
n = 3
res = (1..n).map do |n|
    r1 = rand(30..89)
    r2 = rand(90..119)
    r3 = rand(120..360)
    score = r1 + r2 + r3
    [n, r1, r2, r3, score]
end

#=> [[1, 38, 93, 318, 449], [2, 64, 93, 259, 416], [3, 83, 93, 343, 519]]
```

---

An alternative way of pushing the sum of element into the array is using [Object#tap](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Object.html#method-i-tap):

```
[5,10,15].tap{ |a| a << a.sum } #=> [5, 10, 15, 30]
```

So you could write:

```
[rand(30..89), rand(90..119), rand(120..360)].tap{ |a| a << a.sum }
```

This allows to write a one liner (using [Array#unshift](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Array.html#method-i-unshift)):

```
(1..n).map { |n| [rand(30..89), rand(90..119), rand(120..360)].tap{ |a| a << a.sum }.unshift n }
```

---

**Fixing your code**

Visualise the setup:

```
field = 3 # no user input for example
p athlete = Array.new(5) #=> [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]
p triathalon = Array.new(field){athlete.dup} #=> [[nil, nil, nil, nil, nil], [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil], [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]]
```

**NOTE** `athlete.dup` to avoid reference to the same object.

Once you see your objects (`athlete` and `triathalon`), you can realize that it is not required to iterate over the nested array, just access by index:

```
count=1
triathalon.each do |athlete|
    athlete[0] = count
    athlete[1] = rand(30..89)
    athlete[2] = rand(90..119)
    athlete[3] = rand(120..360)
    athlete[4] = athlete[1] + athlete[2] + athlete[3]
    count+=1
end
```

Improvement: to get rid of the counter use [Enumerable#each_with_index](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index).

Comment: So, I tried your example code, and had the triathlon array print after the loop. It's generating #{field} number of identical arrays. If I use 3 as the user input for field, I'm getting 3 identical arrays. Sample output in next comment. Also, I appreciate the help.

Comment: Please enter the number of athletes competing in the triathalon: 3 
[[3, 80, 102, 193, 375], [3, 80, 102, 193, 375], [3, 80, 102, 193, 375]]

Comment: My bad, in setting up the `triathalon` array it is required to duplicate the object to avoid create an array whit the reference to the same object. I edited. See: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Array.html#method-c-new-label-Common+gotchas

Comment: A small point regarding your last sentence: one could instead use [Enumerator#each_index](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_index), writing `triathalon.each.with_index(1) { |athlete, count| .. }`. The argument `1` causes the index (`count`) to begin at `1`, a convenience.